# How to get an IServiceScope by instance?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I use .NET Core 3.1.
I have a Singleton-service `ILoggerProvider`. I need to give him the Scope, where the ILoggerProvider-caller stays in. But it is impossible. I know that if I use `StackTrace()`, then I can get the ILoggerProvider-caller instance.
Where are all Scopes stored and how to get the Scope by instance?

Comment: can you provide an example of code and what is expected.?

Comment: An example of what? 
`public class DbLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider   {   private readonly IIdempotencyRequestKey _idempotencyRequestKey; // then the constructor ... }`

Comment: It would be nice to see like this: `IServiceScope scope = IServiceScopeHolder.GetScopeByInstance(myServiceThatLivesInScope);`